# How to filter a SPARQL query by its type?

Tags: sparql, rdf, protege, rdfs

I need to find movies that has only thriller type, how can I do it?

```
SELECT ?MOVIE 
WHERE { 

    ?MOVIE movie:name ?name.

}
```

This MOVIE has more than one type, it's a Movie but it's also under type Thriller or Comedy, how can I find a movie with only Thriller type?

Thanks a lot

Comment: add another triple pattern that specifies the type. And yes, it's exactly that simple

Comment: It was easy like that, thanks.